# Is there any tool for montioring java application in windows 7?

Tags: java

I have created Java project.In this project i used file creation,deletion for the file manipulation operation using file handler. so i need to see those file handler while debugging the project.I have tried following command **JPS,JSTACK** and etc.These tools are displaying process id,class name,package name.

But i need to know actual functionality of each class.for example object creation,file creation,objection deleted and etc.
Is there any tool is available for windows?

Comment: VisualVM? (Part of the JDK or a separate download)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-XX:+PrintCompilation` can help you.

The `-XX:+PrintCompilation` flag output looks something like this:

```
1  sb   java.lang.ClassLoader::loadClassInternal  (6 bytes)     
2  b    java.lang.String::lastIndexOf  (12 bytes)
3  s!b  java.lang.ClassLoader::loadClass  (58 bytes)
```

Flags correspond to:

```
b    Blocking compiler (always set for client)  
*    Generating a native wrapper    
%    On stack replacement   
!    Method has exception handlers  
s    Synchronized method
```

[More details](http://blog.joda.org/2011/08/printcompilation-jvm-flag.html).

---

Also, maybe you can try [javamelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) for monitoring your applications.

Here are some screen screenshots:
[image: all charts]

[image]

[image]